# How can I get a value out of my JSON using regex?

Tags: json, regex

Looking to grab that content that comes after "ID":319, In this example it would be 22. Any help would be appreciated.

{"id":754,"content":null},{"id":812,"content":"2021-03-22T15:30:00.000+0000"},{"id":573,"content":null},{"id":319,"content":22},{"id":349,"content":null},{"id":609,"content":null},{"id":820,"content":null},{"id":852,"content":null},{"id":317,"content":null},{"id":345,"content":null},{"id":249,"content":"No"},{"id":622,"content":null},{"id":688,"content":null},

Comment: Don't use regex to parse JSON. Use `import json; obj=json.loads(json_text); print(obj["id"], obj["content"])`. (Also, there is no "ID:319" in your input.)

Comment: I am probably doing something wrng but I just tried that and got no match https://imgur.com/a/AAAOM2h

Comment: What I sent was not a regex, it was Python code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I should have stated that I am using a program called Integromat which is kind of similar to zapier. It recommends I use ECMAScript.

Comment: My bad - I saw "regex" and jumped right into Python. I'm sure ECMAScript has JSON decoding features built in so that you don't need to resort to regex.

Comment: If you're using ECMAscript, then you should be able to deal with the JSON directly as a structure.  JSON means JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: Regex is a powerful tool but not powerful enough to parse JSON, HTML or programming languages. The modern extensions of regex that allow recursion enhance it to the stage where some parsing can be done but the performance is really bad (time and memory). Use a dedicated program like `jq` or a library for your language. What language do you use?

Comment: I am using integromat with is like zapier so I have no clue. All I have is drag and drop and a small box to insert my regular expression see here https://imgur.com/a/QZBZgxT

The only thing they say in the documentation is to use ECMAscript.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regexes to parse JSON.  There are too many edge cases, and there are already tools to do it for you.  In this case, I suggest using `jq`.

If you have the file foo.json

```
[
 {"id":754,"content":null} ,{"id":812,"content":"2021-03-22T15:30:00.000+0000"}
,{"id":573,"content":null} ,{"id":319,"content":22}
,{"id":349,"content":null} ,{"id":609,"content":null}
,{"id":820,"content":null} ,{"id":852,"content":null}
,{"id":317,"content":null} ,{"id":345,"content":null}
,{"id":249,"content":"No"} ,{"id":622,"content":null}
,{"id":688,"content":null}
]
```

Then to get the valid "22" from the record where id is 319, use:

```
$ jq '.[] | select(.id == 319) | .content' foo.json
22
```

The [jq query language](https://gist.github.com/olih/f7437fb6962fb3ee9fe95bda8d2c8fa4) takes some learning, but if you're working with JSON, it will pay off big in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know and have never used Integromat but according to the docs you should not be using **Text Parser** for this, you should be using **Parse JSON**:

https://www.integromat.com/en/help/app/json

https://www.integromat.com/en/integrations/json

This way you can properly process the JSON data without using regular expressions.

You should probably read the documentation for **Parse JSON** module.